# How to use ASP.NET Core 2.1 as the backend of a normal HTML/JavaScript web page?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use ASP.Net Core as the backend of my website. Do I have to use the razor views that come with it or can I use as the backend of a normal web page made from HTML, JavaScript, and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to serve static files, then sure, you can absolutely do that. Just start with a blank ASP.NET Core project and put all your files into the `wwwroot` folder. Everything that’s in there will be served directly.

For just serving static files, an ASP.NET Core application might already be a bit too much, but of course if you have the application set up once, you can always add actual server logic later. So it may be possible that you end up adding an API or other dynamic things to your application later.

Answer (score 1):

Given you configure CORS correctly (if you use it at all), you can call your APIs from anywhere. The caller doesn't need to be a Razor view, as that's just a way to generate HTML.

Comment: excuse me, what is 'CORS'?